# Why do I continue to receive this TypeError: expect is not a function

Tags: javascript, chai, wdio-v4

I'm using chai 4.2.0 and is not working as expected, this is the example.

Receiving this TypeError: `expect is not a function` and wondering why if I'm using a global variable.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

describe("Homepage FAQ Accordion", function () {
    beforeEach(function() {

        console.log(expect.expect);
        browser.url('http://127.0.0.1:8303/');
   })

it("should show first section on page load", function() {

var firstHeight = browser.getCssProperty(".accordion .accordion-item:first-child .accordion-content", "height");

        var firstHeight = browser.getTitle();

        console.log(firstHeight);

        expect(firstHeight.parsed.value).to.be.greaterThan(0);
    })
it("should not show other content", function() {
        var secondHeight = browser.getCssProperty(".accordion .accordion-item:nth-of-type(2) .accordion-content", "Display")

        console.log(secondDisplay);

        expect(secondDisplay.parsed.value).to.equal(none);

    })
})
```

Comment: You never define `expect`? I'm surprised this doesn't throw a `ReferenceError: expect is not defined`

Comment: You've overridden/shadowed `expect` with something else than a function in the scope the provided example runs. Please add some more code so, that we can see how the scopes are constructed.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've added the entire code I have for this issue.

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of `expect` after assigned `chai.expect` to it?